# Undefined property: stdClass::$ AND Trying to get property 'name' of non-object Error in plugin

Tags: plugins, json

I created a function that reads an external API and it creates a custom post "Job" with some custom fields. For development, I created it in a shortcode and can reload the page to trigger it. Works perfectly. I now am trying to transfer this to a plugin with an options page triggered by a button. When I run the import, I get both errors:

**Undefined property: stdClass::$jobs_description in /srv/www/careers/public_html/wp-content/plugins/demand-api-remote-old/functions.php on line 89**

**Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in /srv/www/careers/public_html/wp-content/plugins/demand-api-remote-old/functions.php on line 90**

The JSON data is this format:

```
        {
            "id": 182966,
            "name": "Client Advisor",
            "created_at": "2018-03-12T17:56:28.542Z",
            "status": "Open",
            "employment_status": "Full Time - salary",
            "job_description": "<p><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\"><span style=\"color:black\">Working at Schomp is more than just an automotive career. Employers may claim to &ldquo;promote from within,&rdquo; but we mean it; most of our executive team started as lot techs, client advisors, detailers, and service advisors. Every decision we make hinges on two pillars: being right for our employees, and being right for our customers. If you&rsquo;re ready to finally have an automotive job where you know you&rsquo;re making a difference at any level, apply now.</span></span></span></p>\n\n<p><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\"><span style=\"color:black\">As a <strong>Client Advisor</strong>, you&rsquo;ll be at the forefront of the automotive industry. You will be responsible for generating sales of new vehicles to prospective purchasers, maximizing dealership profitability and maintaining an exceptional standard of customer care. Our ideal candidate is highly motivated and with a competitive edge. You will enjoy going the extra mile for your customers, and thrive on working in a competitive team environment. You will be a problem solver who sees things in an innovative fashion, and can make the complex seem simple. You will have the ability to create a positive buying experience for your customers along with a track record of success.</span></span></span></p>\n\n<p><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\"><span style=\"color:black\">You will have the opportunity to work with a team of people who share your values, and to inspire them to meet and exceed their customers&rsquo; expectations every day. You will receive ongoing training and career development opportunities aligned with your personal goals and aspirations. </span></span></span></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p><strong><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\"><span style=\"color:black\">We Offer:</span></span></span></strong></p>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Competitive compensation package that rewards high-performers</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Medical, Dental and Prescription coverage</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Life Insurance</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">401(k) with company match</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Employee discounts on vehicle purchases, parts and service</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Paid time-off</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Supplemental benefit plans including short-term disability, long-term disability, supplemental life insurance and All-State Insurance products</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Comprehensive employee recognition programs</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Continued training through Schomp Automotive Group and the manufacturer</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Opportunities for career advancement</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Fully equipped workout gym with free on-site personal trainer and yoga instructor!</span></span></span></li>\n</ul>\n\n<p><br />\n<span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\"><span style=\"color:black\"><strong>Responsibilities:</strong></span></span></span></p>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Initiating and maintaining relationships with customers</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Greet and guide customer as they appear on the lot to proceed into the sales process</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Enhance the sales process by demonstrating the vehicles features on the lot</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Taking customers through a thorough needs analysis, making suitable product recommendations and organizing test drives</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Accurately logging activities on the internal lead management system</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Conducting business development and networking activities to generate sales</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Assist management to increase sales by inspecting the lot&rsquo;s vehicles daily reporting any problems to the General Manager</span></span></span></li>\n</ul>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p><strong><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\"><span style=\"color:black\">Qualifications: </span></span></span></strong></p>\n\n<ul>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Prior automotive sales experience not necessary. We are willing to train and develop the right person.</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Individuals with a background in the hospitality and/or restaurant industry are strongly encouraged to apply</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Experience representing a luxury brand helpful but not necessary</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Self-driven and motivated to achieve results</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Excellent communication skills</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Experience generating and/or building a loyal client base highly regarded</span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Knowledge of current trends and news, plus a strong desire to learn more and do more </span></span></span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"color:black\"><span style=\"font-size:14.0pt\"><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica Light&quot;,sans-serif\">Willing to submit to a background check &amp; drug screen prior to employment</span></span></span></li>\n</ul>\n",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "city": "Highlands Ranch",
                    "state": "CO"
                }
            ],
            "remote": false,
            "blind_posted": false,
            "job_family": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Sales",
                "shorten": true,
                "arrange": 13
            },
            "careersite_order": 0,
            "career_site_url": "https://careers.hireology.com/schompautomotive/182966/description",
            "application_path": "/careers/182966/application",
            "career_site_path": "/schompautomotive/182966/description",
            "organization": {
                "id": 7587,
                "name": "Schomp Automotive",
                "type": "Corporate"
            },
            "seo_description": "Working at Schomp is more than just an automotive career. Employers may claim to “promote from within,” but we mean it; most of our executive team started as lo...",
            "seo_keywords": "Schomp Automotive, Schomp Automotive jobs, careers at Schomp Automotive, Auto jobs, careers in Auto, Highlands Ranch jobs, Colorado jobs, Sales jobs, Client Advisor",
            "seo_page_title": "Client Advisor | Highlands Ranch, CO | Schomp Automotive",
            "one_click_apply": false,

        },
```

My code that errors is here:

```
{
    //$app_token = $attributes['app_token'];
    $limit = '100';
    $request_uri = 'https://api.hireology.com/v2/public/careers/schompautomotive?page_size=' . $limit;
    $request = wp_remote_get( $request_uri );
    if( is_wp_error( $request ) || '200' != wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $jobs = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request ) );
    if( empty( $jobs ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ob_start();

   // print_array($jobs);

    foreach( $jobs->data as $jobs ) {
        $jobs_id = $jobs->id;
        $jobs_title = $jobs->name;
        $open_date = $jobs->created_at;
        $jobs_status = $jobs->status;
        $jobs_type = $jobs->employment_status;
        $jobs_description = $jobs->jobs_description;
        $jobs_family = $jobs->jobs_family->name;
        $jobsurl = $jobs->career_site_url;
        $jobs_app_path = $jobs->application_path;
        foreach ($jobs->locations as $location ){
            $jobs_location = $location->city;
        }

         $jobs_query = get_posts(array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_type'         => 'jobs'
        ));
        $post_id = -1;


        if( null == get_page_by_title($jobs_title, OBJECT, 'jobs') ) {
            // Insert the post into the database.
            $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                array(
                'post_type'     => 'jobs',
                'post_title'    => $jobs_title,
                'post_content'  => $jobs_description,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_author'   => 1,
                //'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
                ));
                update_field('field_5cfeb71e121d6', $jobs_id, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb738121d7', $jobs_title, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5d0a57c0c3c62', $open_date, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb746121d8', $jobs_status, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb769121d9', $jobs_type, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb782121da', $jobs_description, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb79c121db', $jobs_location, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb7ad121dc', $jobs_family, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb88cd384c', $jobsurl, $post_id);
                update_field('field_5cfeb8b7d384d', $jobs_app_path, $post_id);
        } else {
            $post_id = -2;
        }

       echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>'
      .'Jobs Importer Finished' . '</p></div>';

  }
}
```

The similar code works perfectly without error if I use a shortcode. Can some fill me in on why my objects are not objects?

Here is `$jobs` in `dump_var` (note I removed data from key "job description" for better readability). I guess the real question is I need help realizing why I can transverse the data in the shortcode, but it changes to an array vs object when I do it through the options page button.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 182966
                    [name] => Client Advisor
                    [created_at] => 2018-03-12T17:56:28.542Z
                    [status] => Open
                    [employment_status] => Full Time - salary
                    [job_description] => 
                    [locations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [city] => Highlands Ranch
                                    [state] => CO
                                )

                        )

                    [remote] => 
                    [blind_posted] => 
                    [job_family] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Sales
                            [shorten] => 1
                            [arrange] => 13
                        )

                    [careersite_order] => 0
                    [career_site_url] => https://careers.hireology.com/schompautomotive/182966/description
                    [application_path] => /careers/182966/application
                    [career_site_path] => /schompautomotive/182966/description
                    [organization] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 7587
                            [name] => Schomp Automotive
                            [type] => Corporate
                        )

                    [seo_description] => Working at Schomp is more than just an automotive career. Employers may claim to “promote from within,” but we mean it; most of our executive team started as lo...
                    [seo_keywords] => Schomp Automotive, Schomp Automotive jobs, careers at Schomp Automotive, Auto jobs, careers in Auto, Highlands Ranch jobs, Colorado jobs, Sales jobs, Client Advisor
                    [seo_page_title] => Client Advisor | Highlands Ranch, CO | Schomp Automotive
                    [one_click_apply] => 
                    [third_party_service_data] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [indeed_apply] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [indeed-apply-apitoken] => b20e5f8adcfd3b39b7c8cf9d2afae9a143a7f431f32a8011b8f23cf62d59b4e1
                                    [indeed-apply-jobid] => 182966
                                    [indeed-apply-jobtitle] => Client Advisor
                                    [indeed-apply-jobcompanyname] => Schomp Automotive
                                    [indeed-apply-joblocation] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1151656
                                            [city] => Highlands Ranch
                                            [created_at] => 2019-02-13T00:24:15.575Z
                                            [updated_at] => 2019-02-13T00:24:15.575Z
                                            [job_id] => 182966
                                            [state_id] => 6
                                            [zip_code] => 80129
                                            [address] => 
                                        )

                                    [indeed-apply-posturl] => https://app.hireology.com/service_endpoints/job/182966/application_form?ref=career_site&ref_m=indeed+apply
                                    [indeed-apply-questions] => https://app.hireology.com/service_endpoints/job/182966/application_form/questions?updated=1530565694
                                    [indeed-apply-phone] => required
                                    [indeed-apply-coverletter] => optional
                                    [indeed-apply-name] => firstlastname
                                    [indeed-apply-jobmeta] => job-meta-button top
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 182972
                    [name] => Certified Service Technician
                    [created_at] => 2018-03-12T18:07:14.816Z
                    [status] => Open
                    [employment_status] => Full Time - salary
                    [job_description] => 
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these lines:

```
$jobs_description = $jobs->jobs_description;
$jobs_family = $jobs->jobs_family->name;
```

You're using "jobs", plural.

But in the actual data it's "job", singular.

So `jobs_description` is an undefined property because the actual property is `job_description`, and `jobs_family` is a 'non-object' because the actual object is `job_family`.

Comment: Damn... That was blind to me... guess I should use a little more variation in names. Outside of the scope of this question, now I have no errors and the code seems to run, I can't get the wp_insert_post to fire. With the action of the button, what am I missing to get it to fire?

Comment: Never mind, same error. The search and replace changed my custom post type to Jobs instead of Job... Damn, need some coffee.